# SimpleDateFormat convert

Tags: java

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("GD_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
```

I want a result like `'GD_20120604_164534'`but the result is `AD156_20120604_165315`

how to set the param can return my willing result.thanks advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`G` is an era designator and `D` represents day, as specified in the `SimpleDateFormat` reference, and:

> Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation. "''" represents a single quote.

Change to:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("'GD_'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
System.out.println("GD_" + format.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `G` and `D` are variables like `yyyy`:

```
G   Era designator  Text    AD
D   Day in year     Number  189
```

You should escape those two letter (I think with single quote)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `G` denotes the era and `D` denotes the day of the year.

One way of going round this and do what you want would be to do something like so:

`String newDate = "GD_" + format.format(new Date());`

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("'GD'_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
```

Use ' to escape your characters